# problem saving outlook messages in my drive

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to save outlook messages in my drive but I got an run time error 287 : "Apllication-defined or object error"

```
Sub extract_outlook_emails()

Dim ap As Outlook.Application

Dim fl As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim it As Outlook.MailItem

Dim space As Outlook.Namespace

Dim i As Long

Dim p As Variant


Dim str As String


Set ap = New Outlook.Application

 

Set space = ap.GetNamespace("MAPI")

 

Set fl = space.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each it In fl.Items

If it.Class = olMail Then

    If VBA.InStr(1, it.Subject, "Product_19854") Then

   

p = SaveSelectMail(it.Subject)


        str = "\c:"&environ("user profile") & p & "-" & VBA.Format(it.ReceivedTime, "ddmmyyyy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) & ".msg"

 it.SaveAs str, OlSaveAsType.olMSG

      
    End If


 End If

Next it


end sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an Outlook folder may contain different kind of items - mail, calendar, tasks, document items and etc. But in the code you are iterating over all items with a type of `MailItem`:

```
Dim it As Outlook.MailItem
...
For Each it In fl.Items
```

You need to define the `it` as object and use the late-binding technology to avoid errors in the code.

Also iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea. To find all mail items with a subject containing keywords (any your search condition) you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

But if you need to search for items in multiple folders you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class instead. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.